# Ski Length For jumping

Tags: equipment, skiing

I am wanting to get into riding the terrain park, and I was wondering what skis  lengths are best for hitting jumps. I've already looked into what the  pros and cons for long skis are for normal skiing, but I can't find anywhere what skis are best for hitting jumps. Thanks!